# Is it possible to achieve array multiplication using this approach

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying below method to calculate product of array of numbers.

```
 var str = [1,2,3];
 alert(str.join('*') * 1);​
```

But it returns me `NaN`.

Is there any other way of doing this.

Answer (score 4):

The ideal would be to use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
alert(str.reduce(function (acc, curr) { return acc * curr; }, 1));
```

[**See it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/rShML/).

`Array.reduce` is not available in IE earlier than version 9, but there should be plenty of implementations to find (e.g. [this one](https://gist.github.com/1043790)).

Comment: @SoI: If you add a definition of `Array.prototype.reduce` as part of your JS code then it will work fine in any browser. Otherwise, just loop over the array and move on.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is evaluating the string as an expression:

```
alert(eval(str.join('*')));​
```

However, as always, if you are using `eval` you should seriously ask yourself if you are doing something wrong.

Consider just looping instead:

```
var result = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) result *= str[i];
alert(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please include disadvantages of using eval() ? And does this method available in all the IE browsers?

Comment: @SoI: It's available in all browsers, but it's risky to use because it will evaluate anything. If you don't have full control over what you evaluate, you can have a cross site scripting vulnerability.